# Like with argument "_" not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I am using the following command with `SQL Server 2008 R2` to display companies name(c_name) whose second alphabet is 'e'. I am not getting any results.

```
select c_name from ind_comp where c_name LIKE '_e'
```

EXPECTED Results:

```
 Rows 1, 4,7,10
```

ACTUAL:
    No rows returned

Sample Table rows (table: ind_comp):

```
Sno c_name          addrs               turnover
1   pesodent        B-12/7 Kolkata      250
2   Colgate         127 Mumbai          519
3   Prestiege       56H Jharkhand       120
4   Relexo          D-45/12 New Delhi   358
5   Bajaj           450, Channai        840
6   TATA            C/90 Bihar          508
7   Reliance        Y-90 New Delhi      700
8   ShaktiBhog      A 120 Punjab        950
9   Kotak Mahindra  B-12 Mumbai         950
10  Pepsi India     5/40 Haryana        600
11  Air India       WZ-90 Goa           1000
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.100).aspx) for `LIKE`? The section on "Using the % Wildcard Character" should make it fairly clear why your query doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your query will only return entries that are 2 characters long that end with an `e`. You need to use the `%` wildcard to include entries of any length greater than 2 characters.

```
SELECT c_name FROM ind_comp WHERE c_name LIKE '_e%'
```

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
select c_name from ind_comp where c_name LIKE '_e%'
```